# how to disable a contract by changing some internal state which causes all functions to revert?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, selfdestruct, solidity-0.6.x

In official documentation of Solidity about Self-destruct instruction is written:

> If you want to deactivate your contracts, you should instead disable
>   them by changing some internal state which causes all functions to
>   revert.

Reference: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#deactivate-and-self-destruct

Can Some one explain me what does mean?

It's sufficient and correct this code to destroy a contract?:

```
function kill() public {
    if (msg.sender == owner)
    // only allow this action if the account sending the signal is the creator
        selfdestruct(owner);
        // kills this contract and sends remaining funds back to creator
}
```

Thanks a lot, 
I'm learning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest to accomplish with a modifier which you add to each function. So something like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0;

contract Example {
    bool _isActive = true;

    modifier checkActive() {
        require (_isActive);
        _;
    }

    function do1() checkActive public {
        // do something
    }

    function do2() checkActive public {
        // do something else
    }

    function setActivity(bool isActive) public {
        // restrict access to this function
        _isActive = isActive;
    }
}
```

Here everything works if the contract's `_isActive` is `true`. But once someone with proper access sets that to `false` all function calls will revert.

And yes your selfdestruct code looks ok.

Comment: I agree this is almost always the best way to go. IMHO, selfdestruct is almost always _not_ the optimal thing to do. https://blog.b9lab.com/selfdestruct-is-a-bug-9c312d1bb2a5